# Trying to create a array with .split and null values after it java

Tags: java, arrays

I tried using the `.split` function with null values to keep the array 20 big.

I should see:

```
String[] N = new String[20];
String M = "hello world tHIS is random 123123 text";
    N = M.split("\\s+", -1);
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(N));
```

With the output:

```
"hello, world, tHIS, is, random, 123123, text, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null"
```

But instead I get:

```
"hello world tHIS is random 123123 text"
```

How do I keep the array as 20 regardless of how long the M value is?

Comment: Iterate over and use `substring`. Or store them in a temp variable.

Comment: Is the -1 necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the `Arrays.copyOf` method and set the length to 20. As the JavaDoc says its padding the array with nulls, just as you need it:

```
int length = 20;
String[] N = new String[length];
String M = "hello world tHIS is random 123123 text";
N = Arrays.copyOf(M.split("\\s+", -1), length);
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(N));
```

Output:

> [hello, world, tHIS, is, random, 123123, text, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]

Comment: could save 20 as a variable, then use it twice

Answer (score 0):

You are reassigning N to M. If you want to keep all the null values, you'll need to save the split string separately and loop over it to assign each index to N.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `StringTokenizer` for this purpose :

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(M);
for (int i = 0; i < N.length && st.hasMoreTokens(); ++i) {
    N[i] = st.nextToken();
}
```

Although the the documentation says :

> StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility
>   reasons although its use is discouraged in new code

It seems to be a good match for your use case as you avoid copying the result of `split`.

Comment: The `StringTokenizer` documentation says that it is a legacy class whose use is discouraged in new code.

Comment: @RealSkeptic yes it does. I have commented on that on my answer. Since it doesn't say "forbidden" and it happens to be good for this particular case, it is worth considering.

Answer (score 0):

The `.split` methods creates a new array with the exact length, and you save its reference. You should resize the resulting array instead. (It does not really resize the array, but creates a copy of it with the correct length, and saves it into the same variable as before):

```
String M = "hello world tHIS is random 123123 text";
String[] N = M.split("\\s+", -1);
N = Arrays.copyOf(N, 20);
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(N));
```